# Preserve querystring on page reload

Tags: visualforce

I've got a VF page to which I've added page messages to capture validation errors.  However, when it picks one up and renders the message, the page reload means I lose the parameters in my querystring, and so I get nulls when looking for them.

How can I preserve my querystring when there is a page message to be displayed?

Comment: Take fields in the objects you are working in and update the object`s field with the query string value before page upload!

Answer (score 0):

```
PageReference currentPage = ApexPages.currentPage();    
/* We first get the current page parameters and pass these to the next page */        
Map<String,String> currentPageParameters = currentPage.getParameters();
PageReference nextPage = new PageReference('/apex/NextPage');
nextPage.getParameters().put('key',currentPageParameters.get('key'));
return nextPage;
```

Comment: I have no control of the next page - it reloads the page when it renders apex pagemessages if there's a validation error on save

Comment: Can u share your sample of code ?

Comment: So I have a VF component on the page that has this :- if ( currentId == null ) {
            currentId = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get( 'id' );
        }

Comment: and on the page controller, validation checks that do this - catch(DmlException err) {
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Error,err.getDmlMessage(0)));

        }

Comment: check with  if ( currentId == null ) { currentId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id'); }

Comment: Are  you calling any render function like action function,action support .. for validating rules ?